# Iterated quotients in GIT

Tags: reference-request, geometric-invariant-theory

Suppose that $G$ is a reductive group that acts algebraically on an affine variety $X$ over an algebraically closed field $k$.

Suppose also that $G$ is equipped with a normal abelian subgroup $N$ such that
the quotient group $G/N$ is finite abelian.

**Example:** $G = \text{O}(2,k)$ and $N= \text{SO}(2,k)$, and $k = \Bbb C$ is the complex numbers.

**My question:** Under what circumstances can I conclude that a categorical/good quotient $X/\!\!/G$ coincides with a categorical/good quotient for $G/N$ acting on $X/\!\!/N$?

That is, under what circumstances is there a birational equivalence between
$X/\!\!/G$ and
$$
(X/\!\!/N)/\!\!/(G/N) \,\, ?
$$
If there is such a result, can someone point me to a place in the literature where it can be found?

Comment: I'm confused about your condition.  You seem just to be assuming that $G$ is an extension of $T$ by a finite, commutative group, which is either automatically reductive if you don't assume that reductive groups are connected (and then do we know that $X//G$ exists?), or never reductive unless $G$ equals $T$.  In either case, what's the point of invoking reductivity? \\ See also [Supposed generalization of $X/(G \times H)\simeq (X/G)/H$ for GIT-quotients](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252478).

Comment: I have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't this follow simply from $(A^N)^{G/N}=A^G$ for invariants?